# How to load the js file from controller in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2-advanced-app

I am using the yii2 and i want to load the js file from controller as in yii 1:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
        Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile('scripts/myfile.js',CClientScript::POS_END);
        $this->render('index');
}
```

But in yii2 i can't load the js file from controller. I can only load the js file directly in view file but not from the controller my code is to load the js file:

```
$this->registerJsFile(Yii::$app->request->BaseUrl . '/js/custom.js', ['depends' => [yii\web\JqueryAsset::className()]]);
```

But this is not working in the controller it works in the view file.

Is there any way to load the js file from the controller in Yii2?

Comment: The question is: why do you need to load in controller instead the view? Yii2 architecture helps you to avoid this mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by Farbrizio, we not sure why you would use the controller to attach the script files but this should do what you are trying to achieve

```
\Yii::$app->getView()->registerJsFile(\Yii::$app->request->BaseUrl . '/js/custom.js', ['depends' => [\yii\web\JqueryAsset::className()]]);
```